# FIWARE orion: command messages to devices are dropped

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, fiware, fiware-orion

I am running an orion docker container for quite some time
"orion": {
"version": "3.2.0",
"uptime": "21 d, 2 h, 19 m, 16 s",
...}
together with (not limited to) mongo 4.2.2,, iota-json 1.19.0 and some mosquitto broker (based on 2.11).

I have connected some devices to the platform and measurement data and commands were working well for me.
I believe it was two days ago when the update of attributes in form of sending commands was not working properly anymore and the following error occured:

*ERROR@2022-01-27T20:19:13.415Z postUpdateContext.cpp[682]: Orion Bug (empty contextAttributeVector for ContextElementResponse 1)*

40% of the commands still arrive at the devices but lots are just lost.

A colleague of mine mentioned we are apparently facing this issue since we updated our VM's OS to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Still... all components run in docker containers in a swarm (all VMs have the same OS and docker engine version). I also checked the orion container's resources and it seems to be fine, it has pretty low load in fact.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Given that it works in a percentage of the cases (60%) it seems to be somekind of problem in the deploymente environment, maybe related with resources.